# Windows service sometimes won't start (eratic behaviour)

Tags: c#, multithreading, service, timer, windows-services

At the moment I'm developing a series of Windows services in C#, that use a timer (from `System.Timers`) to poll the machine they are running on and report stats to a remote listener (remote machine hosts a WCF data service).

The setup is as follows: I have a class that wraps System.Timers.Timer with additional functionality, accepting a generic event handler to be fired when the timer elapses and log information:

```
public class GenericPoller
{
    private EventLog _log;
    private string _componentName;
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer;

    public GenericPoller
        (
            double interval, 
            System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler handler, 
            EventLog log,
            string componentName
        )
    {
        _componentName = componentName;
        _log = log;

        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _timer.Interval = interval;
        _timer.AutoReset = true;
        _timer.Enabled = false;
        _timer.Elapsed += handler;
    }

    public void StartPolling()
    {
        try
        {
            _timer.Enabled = true;
            _log.WriteEntry
            (
                "Timer started for component '" + _componentName
                + "', with " + _timer.Interval + "ms interval."
            );
        }
        catch
        {
            _log.WriteEntry("Failed to start timer for component '" + _componentName + "'.");
        }
    }

    public void StopPolling()
    {
        try
        {
            _timer.Enabled = false;
            _log.WriteEntry("Timer stopped for component '" + _componentName + "'.");
        }
        catch
        {
            _log.WriteEntry("Failed to stop timer for component '" + _componentName + "'.");
        }
    }

}
```

Any one of the services I'm implementing creates a `GenericPoller` in their constructor, and in the `OnStart` method I invoke `StartPolling` via a separate thread to consume as little time as possible inside this method. The service class looks roughly like this:

```
public partial class CPUMonitor : ServiceBase
{
    private GenericPoller _poller;
    Thread _thread;

    public CPUMonitor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _poller = new GenericPoller
        (
            HardwareMonitorCommon.Instance.DefaultPollingInterval,
            PollCPU,
            EventLog,
            "CPUMonitor"
        );
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(_poller.StartPolling));
        _thread.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _poller.StopPolling();
        _thread.Join();
    }

    private void PollCPU(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

            Code to aqcuire CPU stats and report to WCF data service...
    }
}
```

I install the services with the `installutil.exe` command.
The services will *sometimes* fail to start within the allotted time (error 1053), but there doesn't seem to be any pattern to this problem. Failure to start is about 4 attempts out of 10.

I simply can't understand why this happens. The System/Application event log doesn't report any errors or exceptions from the service processes, and I can't figure out why a timeout would occur if all the "heavy lifting" is taking place in a separate thread.

I'm in no way a pro/expert at writing multithreaded code, so I fully expect to be doing something wrong...I just can't see what it is...

---

**EDIT:** the `Main` method remains in the automatically generated `Program.cs` file, and I only modified it to add the components that will be run:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new CPUMonitor(),
            new MemoryMonitor()
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
}
```

Comment: Man, this is a pain.... we have a service that spawns a thread on OnStart method so it starts immediately, but somehow it won't start sometimes and there is no error whatsoever... it can't be reproduced... now and then we receive tickets about this and we are far away to figure it out.

Comment: @JobaDiniz, yeah I never did figure this out. Over time I've stopped manually setting up service entry points like this and instead use TopShelf which allows you to to run your program standalone or install it as a Windows Service. You may want to give it a shot as well!

Comment: I know TopShelf but it won't fix the problem... Behind the scenes TopShelf will still run my class as a WinService...

Comment: @JobaDiniz, it probably won't, but I've taken to using it just to have a standardised way of setting up windows services, and only suggested it as a means of avoiding bugs when coding the entry points.

Granted in my own example there really isn't anything obviously wrong with the code - I've also been unable to reproduce the issue later...